# Meteor app service getting down after a day in production machine

Tags: javascript, meteor, deployment

I am running following command for start the meteor service.

ROOT_URL=http://192.168.2.157/app nohup meteor &

Service is working one day. After that it went down. Is there any problem?

Comment: The `meteor` command serves the app as in a development environment and is not designed for production. Meteor up is designed to bundle and serve your meteor apps in a more stable production environment https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up/blob/master/README.md

Comment: meteor-up is good, but you can also just use the `meteor build` command to generate a production version of your app. It contains a readme that describes everything you need to know to run it.

Comment: when I am running `mup setup` command, getting `Setup Environment: Failed`.